# Inline Styles not rendering in IE7,8,9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background, inline-styles

I know there are 1000 articles out there with issues like this, but they don't seem to be solving my issues.  I am working on a site that was created well before my arrival here at this company, and they basically have a placeholder to add "widgets" to a site.  When a user clicks "add widget" it displays a scrolling list of them.  In IE5 (Quirks Mode) somehow it works perfectly with the widgets but anything after that doesn't work.  It displays the "AddWidgetContainer" div just fine, but not the div elements inside.  Here is the code.  There is no external css since they are doing everything inline because the image is different for every user.  I have tested through and the images are available and everything through the server, but don't display;

```
<div style="margin-left:10px; height:78px; min-height:78px;" id="AddWidgetContainer">

                                <div id="addaccstats" class="WidgetPanel" style="width:190; height:78; display:none; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/account-statistics.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onClick="addWidget('accstats')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addacct_wiz" class="WidgetPanel" style="width:190; height:78; display:none; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/account_wizard.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onClick="addWidget('acct_wiz')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addalerts" class="WidgetPanel" style="width:190; height:78; display:none; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/Alerts.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onClick="addWidget('alerts')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addassets" class="WidgetPanel viewable" style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/assets_under_mgmt.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton " href="#" onClick="addWidget('assets')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addbiz_snap" class="WidgetPanel viewable" style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/biz_snapshot.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onclick="addWidget('biz_snap')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addcomm_snap" class="WidgetPanel viewable" style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/commissions_snapshot.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onclick="addWidget('comm_snap')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addevents" class="WidgetPanel viewable " style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/conferences_events.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onclick="addWidget('events')"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="addcalc" class="WidgetPanel viewable " style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/tools_calculators.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton " href="#" onClick="addWidget('calc')" ></a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="addcrm" class="WidgetPanel viewable " style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/crm.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onclick="addWidget('crm')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addcrmcal" class="WidgetPanel viewable " style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/calendar.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onclick="addWidget('crmcal')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="adddocs" class="WidgetPanel" style="width:190; height:78;  display:none; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/Documents.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                                                                                                                                                                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onClick="addWidget('docs')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addecbr" class="WidgetPanel viewable" style=" width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/ecbr.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onClick="addWidget('ecbr')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addfollow" class="WidgetPanel" style="width:190; height:78;  display:none; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/Follow_up_required.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton " href="#" onClick="addWidget('follow')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addforms" class="WidgetPanel viewable" style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/forms.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onClick="addWidget('forms')"></a>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addholidays" class="WidgetPanel viewable" style="width:190; height:78;  display:inline; float:left; background:url(/applications/images/widgets/add/holidays_events.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <a class="AddWidgetAddButton" href="#" onClick="addWidget('holidays')"></a>
                                </div>  

                                <table border="0" class="AddWidgetButtonContainer" style="display:inline; float:left; line-height:30px; vertical-align:middle; margin:0; width:950px; height:30px; padding:0;">
                                    <tr><td><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkWidgetAddReset"  class="AddWidgetButtonContainerButton" href="COMMunityLink.asp">Reset to default home page</a></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right; float:right; vertical-align:middle;  margin:0px; width:200px; height:30px; "  id="addWidgetCounter"></td>
                                    <td id="paging_buttons" style="width:75px" ><a id="widget_prev" style="background: url('/applications/images/icons/btn_widget_prev.gif') no-repeat; padding:10 12 10 12; width=20px; height:20px; background-position:right" href="#" onClick="prevels();return false"></a>
                                    &#160;
                                    <a id="widget_next" href="#" style="background: url('/applications/images/icons/btn_widget_next.gif') no-repeat; padding:10 12 10 12; width=20px; height:20px; background-position:right" onClick="nextels();return false"></a></td></tr>
                                </table>
            </div>
```

Not even the link elements inside the table display correctly with the background images after Quirks Mode.  I also attached some pics.
Quirks Mode and IE7 Mode
[image]
[image]

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: a fiddle would be awesome

Comment: the site is hosted on an ssl that requires login so you wouldn't be able to access the images regardless through a fiddle, i tried creating this fiddle and referenced the last image to a stock image from google images and it still doesn't render correctly;
http://jsfiddle.net/3XUgh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because width & height should have measurement units, like `px` or `mm`.

`width:190; height:78;` => `width:190px; height:78px;` should fix your problems.

also, width applied to `inline` elements don't do anything.
consider using `inlin-block` for your div's instead of `inline`.

and, `padding: 10 12 10 12` => `padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px` => `padding: 10px 12px`

and finally: `width =20px` => `width:20px`

Here a [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/8hQC8/) with those fixes

Comment: i figured this out just before looking at this.  Thank you for your help and insight on it, I do appreciate it very much!